# Authentication page before loading the main website

Tags: drupal

I am using Drupal 7. I need any user(who has not logged in) to just see the login screen only for authentication before he can traverse the actual website.

How this can be done?I tried to do it using Panels but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a module.

hook_init() is the only hook you will need. Inside hook init grab requested path.

Then just create an if statement that evaluates whether the !user_is_logged_in && is not the same requested path as your login page. Use the  drupal_goto() your login path. Here is all the documentation you need:

Documentation:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7

will look like:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init() {
 $requestPath = request_uri();
 $loginPath = "/login-path";
 if ((!user_is_logged_in()) && ($requestPath != $loginPath)) {
   drupal_goto($loginPath);
 }
}
```